# Automatically Enable Secondary Display When Connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

At my desk, I generally have a laptop plugged into an external monitor (cloned display) with the lid of the laptop closed.

Right now each time plug in the secondary display, I have to open the display properties, enable the display, select that it should be a clone, apply then confirm it worked.

Any way to automate that? (I'm currently on 10.10 - so perhaps that workflow has improved in current releases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

the workflow has indeed improved since then. When I plug in my secondary display to my laptop in Ubuntu 12.04 (lts) . The screen is automatically enabled and all previous configuration (if its tilted , left or right side of my current screen) are remembered.

You should upgrade to a more current distribution.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I know. I'll add this to the reasons I need to update. Good to know.

Comment: Actually testing the latest release, there's some display issue where it blanks both displays when the list is closed (all power events are set to 'nothing'). But it did seem to handle auto-detection better.